# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid Sum Row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex-code, interactive-grid, oracle-apex21.2

I have a table with 2 columns(GAUGE_NAME, CALCULATED_VALUE) and table has values in **Column** screenshot. I create a page and add interactive grid. After that i followed these steps;

Run page -> Action Menu(Interactive Grid) -> Data -> 
Aggregate -> **Column** = CALCULATED_VALUE / **Aggregation** = Sum -> Save

Action Menu(Interactive Grid) -> Report -> Save

And refresh the page. After that, a new column has been added. How can i remove this column?

[Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs34x.png)

[Action Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBVV3.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Actions" menu and choose "Columns" - you can remove it there.

Comment: I can't see this column in there. I added this menu ss.

Comment: Could you describe steps you took (the whole process, starting from "I add sum for calculated value ...") so that we could try it ourselves and see what happens?

Comment: I added the steps to the question

Comment: Right; that's exactly what I did, and there's no additional column in my Interactive Grid. Tested on Apex 20.2. Which version do you use?

Comment: I use version 21.2

Comment: And my page modal dialog. I don't know if this is why

Comment: Tried it on 21.1 (I don't have 21.2), created a modal dialog page (and navigated to it from another page) - no problem either. Try to "fix" it (ha-ha) by logging of, close the browser and start it up again. Sometimes it helps when (my) Apex behaves strange (can't explain why).

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Maybe it's a bug of 21.2. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome; I'm sorry it doesn't work for you ...